# mdx member concatenation in Essbase

Tags: mdx, hyperion, essbase, mdx-query

a complete MDX/Essbase newbie is looking for your help.

I have a MDX query:

```
SELECT
{([Version].[FINAL])} ON COLUMNS
,crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin({ [Period].[Jan],[Period].[Dec],[Period].[Sep] },{ [Entity].[BE08008309], [Entity].[BTSEMEALA] }),{ [Years].[2018],[Years].[2017],[Years].[2014] }),{ [ICP].[ICP] }),{ [Currency].[USD] }),{ [Custom1].[TOPC1] }),{ [Custom2].[TOPC2] }),{ [Custom3].[TOPC3] }),{ [Scenario].[Actual],[Scenario].[Junfor],[Scenario].[PlanRestate] }),{ [Account].[RF_ACCUMDEP],[Account].[COSAMORT] })
ON ROWS FROM [EssRptg.EssRptg]
```

which gives me an output containing a row/tuple, such as:

> (January, BE08008309-North, Central and East HQ Mtmt Adj., 2014, ICP, US Dollar, TOPC1, TOPC2, TOPC3, ACTUAL, ACCUMDEP - Accumulated Depreciation)    4321.878

Could this query be rewritten to concatenate every member with a pipe "|" for instance? Such as:

> (|January|, |BE08008309-North, Central and East HQ Mtmt Adj.|, |2014|, |ICP|, |US Dollar|, |TOPC1|, |TOPC2|, |TOPC3|, |ACTUAL, ACCUMDEP - Accumulated Depreciation|)  4321.878

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Bachatero

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

fyi, I've found a WA rewritting my MDX query to include DIMENSION PROPERTIES [Period].[MEMBER_NAME],[Period].[MEMBER_ALIAS], [Entity.[MEMBER_NAME],[Entity].[MEMBER_ALIAS], and so forth.

my query would then look like the following:

SELECT
{([Version].[FINAL])} ON COLUMNS
,crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin(crossjoin({ [Period].[Jan],[Period].[Dec],[Period].[Sep] },{ [Entity].[BE08008309], [Entity].[BTSEMEALA] }),{ [Years].[2018],[Years].[2017],[Years].[2014] }),{ [ICP].[ICP] }),{ [Currency].[USD] }),{ [Custom1].[TOPC1] }),{ [Custom2].[TOPC2] }),{ [Custom3].[TOPC3] }),{ [Scenario].[Actual],[Scenario].[Junfor],[Scenario].[PlanRestate] }),{ [Account].[RF_ACCUMDEP],[Account].[COSAMORT] }) DIMENSION PROPERTIES [Period].[MEMBER_NAME],[Period].[MEMBER_ALIAS], [Entity].[MEMBER_NAME],[Entity].[MEMBER_ALIAS],[Years].[MEMBER_NAME],[ICP].[MEMBER_NAME],[Currency].[MEMBER_NAME],[Currency].[MEMBER_ALIAS],[Custom1].[MEMBER_NAME],[Custom1].[MEMBER_ALIAS],[Custom2].[MEMBER_NAME],[Custom2].[MEMBER_ALIAS],[Custom3].[MEMBER_NAME],[Scenario].[MEMBER_NAME],[Account].[MEMBER_NAME],[Account].[MEMBER_ALIAS] ON ROWS FROM [EssRptg.EssRptg]

Then I parsed the output of the query while removing unnecessary "[MEMBER_NAME] = " and "[MEMBER_ALIAS] = " strings and by splitting the string by "type: STRING," I was ready to overcome my issue with "comma" inside some of my Member columns which was my intitial problem.

Cheers.
Bachatero